# Minimum voltage drop to run a circuit

Tags: circuits

Disclaimer : this question may be more 'physics' than electric engineering

So suppose you have a circuit with a battery and some other elements, the elements, the battery continuously provides energy to the circuit lets say 'E' by the kirchoff voltage law all this energy should be used up as you loop the circuit. Now my question is how would you find the minimum amount of energy which you would need to run a circuit , or how do you find the current/voltage rating given on the back of electirc products?

Comment: this is, imho, topic-wise very much electronics, but vastly underdefined: You figure out the minimum necessary voltage by actually looking at the circuit; no shortcut can be taken.

Comment: "*... how do you find the current/voltage rating given on the back of electirc products?*" Well, it's written on the label so are you asking how the manufacturer calculates the ratings?

Comment: If it's not an actual product or device, you would end up falling back to physics to look at things like electron band Gap energies etc

Comment: say I have a computer , and it requires some voltage to be run, how would I go onto calculate that minimum voltage for it to run?

Comment: *"say I have a computer , and it requires some voltage to be run, how would I go onto calculate that minimum voltage for it to run?"* - Well, that's easy. Look at the label printed on it. That will be the minimum voltage required for the manufacturer to guarantee it will work correctly.

Comment: I think it is quite obvious that he is not talking about the user, but the developer of the device, and I don't think that this question is supposed to be closed.

Comment: I do not understand why people are thinking that I don't know how to read the voltage rating on the packaging boxs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you design a circuit with parts where you have datasheets. These datasheets will explicitly tell you in which voltage range they will work and the designer of the circuit will make sure, that the parts are supplied by the correct voltage by specifing that as input voltage. If other stuff (e.g. a voltage divider or voltage regulator) is placed in front of that device, the voltage rating for the input voltage will change in a way you can easily calculate.

The manufacturer supplying the sub-part with datasheet (like transistor, IC, whatever) will as well use math and simulations to find the proper voltage range. In addition he will probably do extensive testing to check which voltages lead to failure or degradation.

Comment: so it is basically trial and error to find it?

Comment: Trial and error is surley a big part of the process, but today the maufactures have a lot of experience and very powerful simulation tools. This reduces the amount of testing a lot.

Comment: And it does depent a lot on whether you are talking about  a device (like many parts on a circuitboard) or about the single part like transistor. As I wrote above, when you create a circuit from parts where you have already good specifications in the datasheet you don't have to trial and error that much, you can just do the math during the design process.